Alt+tab freeze when switching from fullscreen application
This just happened to me twice in a row while I was playing a game. Basically I alt-tabbed out of the game, clicked on the application I wanted to alt-tab to, and the entire computer just freezes. This then forces me to reboot my computer, which is very annoying. As far as I can tell, this happens for any fullscreen game, it has happened to make before.

What kind of GPU does your computer have? Does it have integrated graphics or discrete graphics?

If you want to report bugs, you can read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs  but please note the reporting method can vary on details you didn't provide (ie. which Ubuntu product). This is a support site & not a bug reporting site, but for support you'll need to provide Ubuntu product & release details, as your fix maybe just switching kernel stack for example (Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack options; default set by install media used), but we won't know as you've not said what Ubuntu product/release you're using.
